# How to test implicit invokation with DialogFlow

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es, google-home

I'm working up a little dialogflow application and would like to be able to ask it to play music implicitly, much like what happens if I "link" a pandora account to Google Home.

For instance

"Hey Google, play some jazz in the kitchen"

I have my app properly recognizing and handling the intents when they are directly requested, as in...

"Hey Google, ask My Wizzy App to play some jazz in the kitchen"

But that gets cumbersome quick.

I've set up the intents such that they +should+ be recognized as implicit intents (via the Google Assistant integrations page), but they don't actually work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately implicit invocation is not always guaranteed and, for this reason, may not be optimal for the use case you've defined here. The likelihood of implicit invocation for a given user is based on various factors including the relevance and quality of the app. You can find out how better to optimize your app for implicit invocation [here](https://developers.google.com/actions/discovery/implicit#action_discovery).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. After more digging, I did find the clause that mentions exactly what you say, that implicit actions are not necessarily gauranteed. However, Music services appear to have "special treatment'. You'll note in the google home app, you can select one of the several available services (for instance, google music, pandora, or spotify) and once you've done that, when you ask for certain things, for instance, "Hey google, play some Jazz in the ktichen", that service will be invoked directly.

Comment: After more digging, turns out you have to register with Google for the Early Adopters program, fill out some paperwork and hope to get accepted to be able to create and be listed as a "Music service provider". Im in the process of doing so now, so we'll see!